# Object at URL of type 'website' is invalid because a required property 'og:title' of type 'string' was not provided

Tags: facebook, sharing, facebook-opengraph

In my live URL Facebook sharing not working. Please view the "og" meta tags:

[image: og meta tag details]

After that I'm going to check the my live URL Facebook scrab information: 
[Fetch new scrape information](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/). But it shows the error message:

[image: Fetch new scrape information]